# React extracting types/tags and passing values to children

Tags: reactjs

I am playing with React and trying to make for each component

Usage:

```
<ul>
  <ForEach items={['value 1', 'value 2']}>
    <li />
  </ForEach>
</ul>
```

Component:

```
render() {
  const { items } = this.props;
  const { children } = this.props;
  const Tag = children.type;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {
        items.map(item => (
          <Tag key={shortid.generate()}>{item}</Tag>
        ))
      }
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

This fully works. Now I am thinking about outputting more complex children html, e.g.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <span>Value 1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span>Value 2</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

How would be a proper way to pass value to child? E.g.:

```
<ul>
  <ForEach items={['value 1', 'value 2']}>
    <li>
      <span>{placeholderForValue}</span>
    </li>
  </ForEach>
</ul>
```

And another thing, how could I extract `li` and `span` and `here goes another nested element` from `this.props.children`? Would I need to loop in depth and outputting elements as deep they are?

Thank you in advance. If there are any questions, please ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more usual way to do this is by using `items.map(item => ...)`.

However, if you really want to do it this way, the best form would be by using a render prop as a child.

ForEach render method:

```
render() {
    const { items } = this.props;
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {items.map(item => (
            this.props.children(item)
        ))}
    </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

usage:

```
<ForEach items={['value 1', 'value 2']}>
    {value => (
        <li>
            <span key={value}>value</span>
        </li>
    )}
</ForEach>
```

You are essentially extracting the `items.map` function into a component that is more verbose and harder to understand, this is why most people don't usually do it this way.

Comment: would you say it makes more sense to make specific "for each" components, not generic ones, as this then allows you to add specific behavior to the type of "for each" component? Because I have seen components use the above pattern to great success, but very rarely have I seen just a generic "for each"... A animated list component would be a good example of a "specific" "for each"...

Comment: Oh yeah, I've definitely seen some components pull that off. If you have more complex conditions for showing the components or want to wrap them in transitions or something like that, it definitely is a good way to go (`react-virtualized` for example does something like this). I thought you just wanted a generic items.map component.

Comment: And if you do that, childrens as functions is definitely a good way to go.

Comment: I'm not the OP :)

Comment: Hahaha sorry :D

Comment: @GarrettMotzner can you provide some samples you have seen? Tnx.

Comment: @be-codified: like jabsatz mentions, [react-virtualized](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/) is a good one. It uses the rowRenderer prop instead of the children prop (but it wouldn't have to). Also take a look at the react [animations add-on](https://reactjs.org/docs/animation.html). It uses children directly (not in a render function), and sometimes keeps them mounted longer than normal.